# Return top level key based on presence of key at subobject

Tags: yaml, yq

I have a YAML file like this

```yaml
---
apps_membership:
  children:
    apps_prometheus:
      children:                                                                                                       
        group_1:
        group_2:
    apps_logstash:
      children:
        group_3:
        group_4:
    apps_alertmanager:
      children:
        group_1:
        group_2:
```

I try to get the groups when i look for a vm, for example is I look for **group_1** I want to get

```
apps_prometheus
apps_alertmanager
```

I'm trying with a combination of [kislyuk/yq](https://github.com/kislyuk/yq) and jq with the map / key / contains

----- Test with paths command

If i use the command
`yq -r '.apps_membership.children | paths'`
I get this result:

```
[
  "apps_prometheus"
]
[
  "apps_prometheus",
  "children"
]
[
  "apps_logstash"
]
[
  "apps_logstash",
  "children"
]
[
  "apps_alertmanager"
]
[
  "apps_alertmanager",
  "children"
]
```

If i change the yaml with

```
    apps_alertmanager:
      children:
        group_1: ""
        group_2: ""
```

I get the desired output:

```
[
  "apps_alertmanager"
]
[
  "apps_alertmanager",
  "children"
]
[
  "apps_alertmanager",
  "children",
  "group_1"
]
[
  "apps_alertmanager",
  "children",
  "group_2"
]
```

How can i use the command paths to also get null values ?

Comment: What version of `yq` do you have? Post the output of `yq --version` and post a complete YAML file

Comment: yq version : yq 2.12.0 and jq version:jq-1.5-1-a5b5cbe i truncate the rest of the file because the yaml is always the same then

Comment: @Inian, i just tested the paths command on an ubuntu release and it works well.... looks like there is an issue with debian buster...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In [kislyuk/yq](https://github.com/kislyuk/yq) you could use the `paths` function available in `jq` to filter for the key name

```sh
yq -r '.apps_membership.children | paths | select(.[-1] == "group_1")[0]'
```

Comment: thanks you for your answer but it return no value, when i use just paths, it doesnt go till the last level with the group keys., it stop on children ones

Comment: Sorry but i tried again in a vm with a fresh install of jq + yq and i get no result with this command and the test yaml i provided :/ looks like path doesnt go till the last level, if i replace group_1 on your command by children i get a result

Comment: the command isnt working on linux mint 19, but upgrading to 20 does...

Comment: @lotusnoir: I doubt it has anything to do with your Linux version. Check your `jq` and `yq` versions on both. Also upvote on the answer if it helped you